# iOS 11 beta 4 presentRenderbuffer crash

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, gpuimage, ios11

My app crashes on iOS 11 beta 4 (15A5327g) when [EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] method is called. It happens only when I debugging in Xcode. When I launch app manually it doesn't crashed. On versions lower than iOS 11 beta 4 it doesn't crashed as well. How can I prevent this issue? You can see crash details in screenshot

[image]

Comment: @Rabbid76 I suppose any application will crash trying to call [EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] on iOS 11 beta 4. You can check.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I provide screenshot to show stack trace and exception

Comment: Screenshots are not searchable - transpose the actual text.

Comment: I got the same crash stack trace on iOS 11 beta 4. It would crash when debugging, but worked fine when I launched the app with my finger.

Comment: I get the same crash, looks like a regression bug in beta 4. Infuriating. I normally avoid beta iOSes but the lure of ARKit was too strong. Now I'm screwed for a test device for my main project. Thanks Apple!

Comment: It seems that Apple fixes this issue in Xcode 9.0 (9A235)

Answer (score 40):

[Hodge's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375569/3419541) works.
Here is a screenshot of how to set the *GPU Frame Capture* argument to "Disabled" (in "Edit Scheme" window)
[image: disabling GPU Image Capture]

Comment: Its not working for me. Here is an issue https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x1/48341

Answer (score 21):

I was experiencing this same issue and a workaround I discovered is to disable GPU frame capture in my Xcode product scheme.

Comment: Seems like a bug in beta (iOS 11 or Xcode 9). I have a similar issue but not in -presentRenderBuffer (because I am using GLKView). The workaround helps to prevent crashing. Similarly, the last reached frame in the main thread is SCNGetPerformanceStatistics.

Answer (score 0):

disable frame capture in scheme, then crash disppeared